# EventEmitter: how to send the result back from the event handler to the "host" component

Tags: angular

I have a child component with an `@Output` parameter:

```
@Output updateThis: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>;
```

And:

```
this.updateThis.emit(myObject);
```

I have a parent component that handles the event. It then calls a service to update the object:

```
<my-component (updateThis)="onUpdateThis($event)" />
```

And this is my question. After the parent component tries to modify the object, I need to signal the child component whether it could update it or not (i.e. whether the service threw an error or not).

How could I signal the result back to the child component? One idea is to add a new property to `myObject` (i.e. `hasUpdateError`). But are there any other ways? For example, I have seen that `EventEmitter` has a subscribe method, but I wouldn't know how to use it in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shared service would be nice perhaps with observables. So, when the parent component receives the event from the child component, you could have a public set method to change the state of the Subject with `.next`. The child component would subscribe to the Observable of that Subject to get the new state.

It is explained quite nicely here https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service. The same logic can be applied for any component and not only for child-parent.